# Probability of exactly one defective item in a sample of three....

Tags: statistics

> In order to determine the quality of a shipment of 20 parts, a sample
>   of 3 items is randomly selected without replacement from the shipment.
>   Four of the 20 items in the shipment are actually defective. Let Y be
>   a random variable representing the total number of defective items in
>   the sample. Then P(Y = 1) is

This is what I got so far, is this correct?

$P(Y=1) = \frac{C^4_1C^{20-4}_{3-1}}{C^{20}_3} $
$ = \frac{4 \cdot 120} {1140} \approx 0.421$

Comment: uninformative title....please improve

Comment: Did either answer help you?

Answer (score 3):

The distribution is not binomial, it is **hypergeometric**. There are $\binom{20}{3}$ **equally likely** ways to choose $3$ items. There are $\binom{4}{1}\binom{16}{2}$ ways to choose $1$ bad and $2$ good.

Comment: I didn't get the ${4 \choose 1} {16 \choose 2}$

Comment: This counts the number of ways to get $1$ bad and the remaining $2$ good. The bad ccan be chosen from the $4$ bad available in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways, and for each such way there are $\binom{16}{2}$ ways to choose the $2$ good from the $16$ available.

Comment: Can you check to see if I got it right?

Comment: On top you should have $C^{16}_2$, not $C^{17}_2$. The full expression then simplifies to $\frac{8}{19}$, approximately $0.421$.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> ...a sample of 3 items is randomly selected without replacement...

This can be modeled using a hypergeometric distribution (because there is no replacement; therefore dependent) and there is only success and failure.

Using this general formula:

$P(X = k) = \dfrac{{a \choose k} {n - a \choose r - k}}{n \choose r}$

where there are $n$ items, $a$ of which are successes (defective). A random sample of $r$ items are taken, $k$ of which are successes.

So, I say the variables correspond to the following values:

```
n = 20
a = 4
r = 3
k = 1
```

$P(X = 1) = \dfrac{{4 \choose 1} {20 - 4 \choose 3 - 1}}{20 \choose 3}$

$P(X = k) = \dfrac{4 \times 120}{1140}$

$P(X = k) = \dfrac{8}{19}$